# How to filter the list of objects by price of promotions

Tags: java

How do I filter say if I have list of products associated with metadatas like price, promotions etc.. how would I filter by price range of by promotions...

```
public class Products {
    private String name;
    private int weight;
    private String promotion;
    private String nutrition;
    private int price;
    //constructor ,, getter, setters
}
```

I will pass list of products to a `arraylist` and want to filter by price or promotion and it should display me only those come under that criteria..

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java8 you can use the Streams API to create a new list filtered from the existing list. Say you have an ArrayList of Products in a variable called list, and you only want the ones with price equal to 30, then it would look like this...

```
final List<Prouduct> filtered = list.stream()
                                    .filter((elt) -> elt.getPrice() == 30)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
You will also have to change the access modifyers for your variables from private to public.

You will have to iterate over each object in the array and check if the values match with the filter

Example:

```
int filter=10;
for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++){
if(array[x].weight==filter){
System.out.println(array[x].name);
}
}
```

where `array` is an array of objects of the product class

Comment: Not `public`, you can access them using getters.

Comment: @Nichar I am assuming that the class is in another package.